# How to add custom fields to category pages?

Tags: php

I have a website about HTML5 games, built with some PHP script.

One of its plugins you can create custom fields for each category page.

I created different custom fields (description text) for each category page.

But when I want to show these fields on category pages, unfortunately each category page shows all custom fields of all categories.

Here is a code I added to category.php file:

```
<?php
    
    $categories = get_all_categories();
    foreach ($categories as $category){
        $category_info = $category->get_field('category_info');
    
        if(is_null($category_info)){
            $category_info = 'no info';
        }
        echo $category_info;
    }
?>
```

I want to show only 1 custom field (which is particular to each category) in every category page.

Here is get_all_categories() default function of the script:

```
function get_all_categories(){
    $data = Category::getList();
    return $data['results'];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Well we would need to know how this data is stored, I assume there woudl be a identifier so you knew which info went with each page, but without more information we cannot really help

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you. Added some info about function.

Comment: Still not enough. How do you save this info

Comment: @RiggsFolly get_all_categories() function is on another file which is located in "includes" folder. With plugin, you can create custom fields. So for each category, I created description custom field with different content.